# что читается scanf("%*c")?

Tags: c

что читается scanf("%*c")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта конструкция считает из входного потока любой символ и никуда его не сохраняет. То есть это способ пропустить один символ.

Для примера прочитаем каждый второй символ:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    while (scanf("%*c%c", &c) == 1) {
        putc(c, stdout);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc scanf_c.c
>
> $ echo "Hello, world!" | ./a.out 
> _e_l_,_w_r_d_
>
> $ echo " Hello, world!" | ./a.out 
> _H_l_o_ _o_l_!
> $
> ```

P.S. Я поправил ответ, так как ошибочно написал что `%*c` пропускает пробельные символы. Это не так. Чтобы пропустить пробелы в формат надо явно вставить пробел:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    while (scanf(" %*c%c", &c) == 1) {
        printf("_%c", c);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc scanf_c_skipws.c 
>
> $ echo "Hello, world!" | ./a.out
> _e_l_,_o_l_!
> $ echo " Hello, world!" | ./a.out
> _e_l_,_o_l_!
> $ echo "   Hello,   world!" | ./a.out
> _e_l_,_o_l_!
> $
> ```

P.P.S. Спасибо [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp) за комментарий.

Comment: Она считает **любой** ближайший символ. Чтобы считать ближайший непробельный надо написать `scanf(" %*c");` (поставить в формате пробел перед `%*c`)

Comment: @avp, спасибо! Исправил ответ.

Comment: большое спасибо!